# WPF Application Crashing Without throwing any Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, quickbooks

Iam created a WPF Application in framework 4.5 and deployed as ClickOnce Application.
  It is for Connecting and write the QuickBooks(3rd party) Software.
The Application is working fine On every system except few systems.
In few systems it is got crashed even if I am keeping the Application as idle.(After Connecting to the 3rd party software).
I don't know what is exactly happens with only few systems.

After crashing it is immediately Opens the JIT.
In that the following call stack i had

```
4036a9ae()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

I have added all exception handling mechanisms includes catching Dispatcher Unhandled exception and Unhandled exceptions. even though it is not catch any of the exceptions.

Can anyone tell me, how to resolve this issue or How to find out the exact reason behind it?
The last two weeks I am trying to resolve it.
[image]

My event Logs shows below

```
Exception code: 0xc00001a5
Fault offset: 0x00056738
Faulting process id: 0xe9c
```

Comment: Are you calling _native_ code anywhere?

Comment: i did not get that? what it means? calling native code?

Comment: Are the specs the same between machines where it works and doesn't work? For example OS version, x86 or 64?

Comment: Yes. Everything is same. all are 64 bit Operationg Systems.

Comment: You need to check the Event Viewer and look for error, warning, or information for your application

Comment: My event Logs iam added in the Question. Please check.

Comment: can you use try catch statement in the MainWindow constructor ? with console opened

Answer (score -2):

Goto project properties of your solution and set the application build start type to Console Application, then in the Constructor of MainWindow use try catch something like below

```
public MainWindow()
{
   try{
   InitializeComponent();
   //you remaining code
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
     Console.Out.Writeline(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

then deploy on the pcs where your app crashes...and see in the console whats the error

Comment: There does not exist a `Console.out` property or field.

Comment: This is not Java, no Console.Out guys.

Comment: @WingerSendon: it's C# WPF as specified in question. And there is Console.Out.Writeline is a valid method. For more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out?view=netcore-3.1